# A cutom.js file is not working properly in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am building a React app and i have pages like about, home and contact. I navigate in the app with react-router-dom. The problem is i have a custom.js file that i have in the public folder that handles accordion slider i have in the about page.
Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
initAccordions();
function initAccordions()
  {
    if($('.accordion').length)
    {
      var accs = $('.accordion');

      accs.each(function()
                {
        var acc = $(this);

        if(acc.hasClass('active'))
        {
          var panel = $(acc.next());
          var panelH = panel.prop('scrollHeight') + "px";

          if(panel.css('max-height') == "0px")
          {
            panel.css('max-height', panel.prop('scrollHeight') + "px");
          }
          else
          {
            panel.css('max-height', "0px");
          }
          $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
        }

        acc.on('click', function()
               {
          if(acc.hasClass('active'))
          {
            acc.removeClass('active');
            var panel = $(acc.next());
            var panelH = panel.prop('scrollHeight') + "px";

            if(panel.css('max-height') == "0px")
            {
              panel.css('max-height', panel.prop('scrollHeight') + "px");
            }
            else
            {
              panel.css('max-height', "0px");
            }
            $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
          }
          else
          {
            acc.addClass('active');
            var panel = $(acc.next());
            var panelH = panel.prop('scrollHeight') + "px";

            if(panel.css('max-height') == "0px")
            {
              panel.css('max-height', panel.prop('scrollHeight') + "px");
            }
            else
            {
              panel.css('max-height', "0px");
            }
            $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
})
```

The accordion slider only works when i reload the about page but when i navigate in the app to home or any other page and comeback to the about page the accordion slider doesn't, it only works when i reload the about page.

Comment: is this jquery object pointing at a react component? `var accs = $('.accordion');` because react will have probably removed it from the DOM, and then add a new instance, when you return.  It's hard to mix JQuery and react. if you really want to do this,  you would need to reattach your jquery each time the component mounts, in the component did mount lifecycle method

Comment: Yes $('.accordion') is a div with accordion class inside a react component. how do  reattach the jquery in custom.js each time the component mounts.

Comment: its pretty nasty, but you recall your: `initAccordions();`  you may need to redesign

Comment: React doesn't allow any imports outside the src directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that initAccordion should be implemented in React to work properly but to manipulate the dom with jquery you have to install jquery

```
npm i --save jquery
```

To minpulate a specific element you need to create a reference to that element and warp it with the $. Here is an example.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Example extends Component{
  $(this.div).css("background-color", "red");
  render(){
    return(
      <div ref={node => this.div=node}>test</div>
    );
  }
};

export default Example;
```

I think that is the approach this issue.